# Flair for dark style overrides style on page it's on

Tags: bug, status-declined, flair

In the [flair-dark.css](https://superuser.com/content/flair-dark.css) file (used with the dark flair theme), there is a style defined for `body`. No other theme has this defined, and it causes that theme to force the page you place the item on to have a black background, if you use the javascript version.

Could this be fixed please?

Comment: A workaround is to stick `!important` on the CSS for `body` on your own stylesheet, but it should not be nessecary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This style of flair is deprecated in favor of image flair -- which obviously will not have this problem.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/flair-now-even-flairier/